# Printing List of Realtime Database Objects

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to print a list of objects into an HTML table. I'm very new to Angular. I've been watching through Mosh tutorials on Udemy, but they don't exactly match up with what I'm building. It my case, the DB structure is different.

Here's the component code:

```
import { AngularFireDatabase } from '@angular/fire/database';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-live-updates',
  templateUrl: './live-updates.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./live-updates.component.scss']
})
export class LiveUpdatesComponent {
  stocks$: Observable<any[]>;

  constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.stocks$ = db.list('/main').valueChanges();
  }
}
```

Here's the structure of the data:
[image]

I'm kind of stumped on how to print out each value into a table.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this stackblitz. 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eou7uy

Basicaly, you have to get the element you main data and loop on it on your angular template.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th *ngFor="let col of columns">
      {{col}}
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let element of stocks$ | async">
    <td *ngFor="let col of columns">
      {{element[col]}}
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And you have to declare your columns ('am', 'carb', 'cyl' ....).
Make senses ?